# In Box2D / Cocos2D for iPhone, how can you tell whether a given touchjoint / mousejoint is touching a given body?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Say you have `B2body *bodyA` and `b2MouseJoint *mousejointA`.

How can you check whether bodyA is connected to or touched by mousejointA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(mouseJointA->GetBodyB() == bodyA){ //Bingo};
```